# Простой запрос mySql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `product` LEFT JOIN `category_product` ON (product.category = category_product.id) WHERE (category_product.seo_url = 'category1')`
```

Обе таблицы содержат `name` и `seo_url`. Вопрос, как я могу явно указать, что уже на сервере нужно брать `name` и `seo_url` из таблицы `product`? P.S. Пробовал использовать `as` но ничего не получилось(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 вариант: использовать имя_таблицы.имя_столбца

```
SELECT
product.name, product.seo_url
FROM `product` 
LEFT JOIN `category_product` ON (product.category = category_product.id) 
WHERE (category_product.seo_url = 'category1')
```

В полученной таблице столбцы будут называться `name`, `seo_url`.

Также попробуйте вариант `SELECT *, product.name, product.seo_url ...` - посмотрите что получится.

## 2 вариант: использовать AS

```
SELECT
product.name AS `product_name`, product.seo_url AS `product_seo_url`
FROM `product` 
LEFT JOIN `category_product` ON (product.category = category_product.id) 
WHERE (category_product.seo_url = 'category1')
```

Столбцы будут называться `product_name` и `product_seo_url`.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте имя таблицы ка префикс. Формат tablename.fieldname

Например

```
SELECT product.name, product.seo_url FROM
```